# RelativeLayout add multiple view one below another

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I want to make  add button that add the views one below another. I dont want a Listview. I tried settings id's on each views and then add using setIDs but when I click on the button the views  are created excacly on the same spot.

```
    final Button addView = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addView);
    mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_mainID);
    final RelativeLayout rv = new RelativeLayout(MainActivity.this);
    rv.setId(-1);
    TextView tx = new TextView(this);
    rv.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorAccent));
    rv.addView(tx);
    mainLayout.addView(rv,100,100);

    addView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RelativeLayout view = new RelativeLayout(MainActivity.this);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams  params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200,200);
            view.setId(id);
            TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            tv.setText("TEXT"+id);
            view.addView(tv);
            view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.colorPrimary));
            params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, id--);
            mainLayout.addView(view,params1);
            id=id+2;
        }
    });
```

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:id="@+id/activity_mainID"
    >
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/addView"
    android:text="ADD"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT: I solve my problem using LinearLayout, but still dont know what is incorrect in my first solution. If someone discover it please share with me.

Comment: Why don't you use linearLayout ?

Comment: Because i want it to be clickable and thought if the setId could be useful

Comment: you can use setTag and getTag

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do the same and faced odd problems when my initial id was -1, 0 or 1. Setting it to a higher initial number (I set it to 4) and suddenly everything works as expected. I guess the reason is that these values represent constants in the `ViewGroup` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/activity_mainID">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/addView"
            android:text="ADD"
            android:layout_below="@+id/activity_mainID"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```